How can I fix an issue with restoring custom Nuget Packages?
I have recently started working on an already existing .net project but I am facing problems with building it as it keep facing an "Unable to find package" errors.
Here is a picture of the errors:

I have already placed these packages where I should place them but it didn't work.
I have placed a packages folder in the main solution directory and added it to the package manager settings as shown below:

But this didn't fix the issue as I am still getting the same type of errors.
Can someone assist in fixing this issue and suggest what I can do?
Thank you.

I'm not sure whether those packages are private or public, what if you create a new project and go to NuGet Manager and try searching for them if still exists or deprecated\removed..

From looking at your error message, it seems that the packages cannot be found on any sources you configured. Please check the following suggestions to see if the issue persists.

Creating new project from scratch still doesn't show these packages in Nuget manager. @MustafaMutasim

List the names of those packages in your question

From looking at the error Unable to find package 'PackageId'. No packages exist with this id in source(s):xxx.
It looks like the packages cannot be found on any sources you configured.
For this issue, please follow suggestions below to troubleshoot.
1.Examine the project's dependencies in Visual Studio to be sure you're using the correct package identifier and version number. If you are usingPackageReference, please open your .csproj file to check ackage identifier and version number.
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="your package ID" Version="versio number" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>

If you are using packages.config,please check it in your project root.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="xxx" version="xxx" targetFramework="xxx" />
</packages>

2.Please check that the NuGet configuration identifies the package sources you are expected to be using.
You can also run the following command to lists all configured NuGet sources and check if local(C:\Projects\backend\packages) exists.
dotnet nuget list source

3 Try to add your package using a specified source to see if the package can  be installed..
dotnet add package "your package id" -s "your local feed"

4.Navigate to  Nuget Package Manager->General. Click button "Clear All Nuget Cache(s).
Hope it can help you.
UPDATE

Can you tell me how custom packages files should look like or the extensions?

A nuget custom packeg should be a .nupkg file. It will be generated when you pack your project.

For more information about how to create and publish a nuget pacakge, please read the doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli

Hello. I followed what was recommended. The project is using "ProjectReference", the packs are listed correctly.
The problem might be with the custom packages themselves as starting a new separate solution, the Nuget manager cannot detect the packages either.
Can you tell me how custom packages files should look like or the extensions?
The files were given to me so multiple of these packages just have folders and files with .sln in them.

Hi @xTMx, updated the answer. Please check to see if it can help you.
